Video Errors when using VLC or cv2.VideoCapture to view webcam but not cheese
Recently I have been trying to set up WSL2 to run Ubuntu 22.04 and OpenCV. I have successfully installed everything and have used usbipd and a WSL2 Kernel that enables usb webcam support to allow wsl access to my webcam. This was verified by using cheese to successfully view the camera.
However, whenever I try to view the webcam through either vlc or by running an OpenCV VideoCapture() object the camera frames become sliced and segmented. I can tell that they are still live as the slices I can see follow my movements. Does anyone know why this may be or what I can do to solve the issue?
Also let me know if any additional information is needed.
Cheese:
Cheese Webcam Image
VLC:
VLC Image
VLC terminal Outputs:
VLC terminal outputs when opening the webcam as a capture device
Ubuntu 22.04
Logitech C920 HD Pro Webcam
Codec identified by vlc: Packed YUV 4:2:2, Y:U:Y:V (YUY2)
Tried:

Restarting Ubuntu
Shutting down wsl and restarting
Unbinding the webcam and rebinding + reattaching it to wsl
uninstalling cheese
reinstalling vlc

UPDATE
After playing around with things more, it is likely an issue with the default webcam settings and the YUV format. Changing the Opencv code to specify the MJPG format and an FPS limit fixes the issue in OpenCV. It seems though that every time I open VLC it resets the webcam settings to their defaults even if I have previously changed them using v4l2-ctl. I will try creating a new default profile for the webcam to see if that will fix it within vlc.
Update 2
Adding a udev rule didn't seem to work for me. I will probably just give up on VLC since the main motivation came from wanting to use OpenCV and that is now working. I will leave this open in case someone knows how to fix it later on but it is no longer a priority for me.
